# functional javascript - function declaration vs function expression?

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming, expression, declaration

What are pros/cons of function declaration vs function expression when the function is meant to be recursive?

Is there any conventions one should try to follow?

Comment: Give some examples of what might be better or worse.

Comment: Whether it's recursive or not doesn't make much difference [except in some older browsers](https://kangax.github.io/nfe/).